# why local variable 'x' referenced before assignment though i am using it after assignment

Tags: python

In the below code, I wrote this code to find the set of prime numbers in a specific range.

I am getting output as:

```
local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

(note: I am using Jupiter notebook). I am getting the same error lot of times.

```
def prime_list(*args):
    limit=args[0]
    primelist=[]
    for y in range (0,limit):
        factor=0
        for x in range(1,y+1):
            if(y%x)==0:
                #print("entered in to modulo loop")
                factor=factor+1
        if(factor<=2):
            #print("{} is prime number".format(y))
            primelist.append(x)
    return primelist
prime_list(10)
```

Comment: Try to figure out what happens for `y = 0`.

Comment: You have just defined the `x` variable in the loop scope, but you are referencing it later in the `if` clause.

Comment: @CodePope that's not the problem (edit: that causes the error). The problem is that the loop does not run for `y = 0`.

Comment: @timgeb You are right. But it is a bad idea to reference a `x` even if the loop runs.

Comment: The error message can be translated to "you have a code path where x is not set". So, find where x is set and consider the conditions where that code block doesn't run. This is valuable to do in general because it often tells you where your error paths are and you can code to handle it.

Comment: @CodePope yeah usually that practice is hard to follow.

Comment: @CodePope - No, its a normal thing to do. Any time your loop is accumulating something or looking for a limit, its a reasonable way to go. You just have to account for the case where the loop didn't run at all.

Comment: The error here is that 0 and 1 are not prime numbers. It should be `for y in range (2,limit):`

Comment: @tdelaney, in a for each loop it is definitely not a normal thing to use the for each variable outside the loop. Many programming languages like C#, C++, Java... prevent it by default. Python does not restrict you, but it is not a good way of programming paradigm to use it and as you can see it is the source of bugs.

Comment: @PrashantNegi Because `for x in range(1,y+1)` is equal to `for x in range(1,1)`. So no iteration is done.

Comment: @CodePope - What? These languages let you define a variable at function scope, set it in a loop, and use it after the loop. If your loop doesn't set the value, its on you to make sure you handle it. Pythons's local variables are all function scope, exactly like all of those other languages.

Comment: @tdelaney, in none of these languages you can reference a foreach variable outside the function, but in Python you can if the loop iterates at least once. And this is the big difference between a dynamic language like python and the other static programming languages regarding this issue. In Python the following code: (https://justpaste.it/3xsrn) would work, but in none of the other programming languages.

Comment: @CodePope -So what? Python's for/else idiom lets you inspect items in an iterable. If you get the value you want, `break`. If not (including the loop didn't run at all) the `else:` is there to take action (set a default, return, raise, etc...). This is a principle feature of the language. Look, you and I are going to disagree, but this is how the language works and I certainly do take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1):

You should insert `y` in the `primelist`:

```
def prime_list(*args):
    limit=args[0]
    primelist=[]
    for y in range (0,limit):
        factor=0
        for x in range(1,y+1):
            if(y%x)==0:
                #print("entered in to modulo loop")
                factor=factor+1
        if(factor<=2):
            #print("{} is prime number".format(y))
            primelist.append(y)
    return primelist

prime_list(10)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: but why in general i am getting this error lot of times(i mean in different programs).. what mistake i am doing??

Comment: @SuneeldattaKolipakula Are you asking what the bug in your code is?

Comment: @SuneeldattaKolipakula you were trying to reference `x` out of its scope.